# Manually setting up integral weights of a 2-2-2 neural network.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, machine-learning, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

- inputs and outputs are both binary.
- hidden layer and output layer have biases.
- function to be modelled is f(i1, i2) = 2 - i1 + i2
- transfer function is sigmoid at hidden and output layers, and the final outputs are obtained by hard limiting at 0.5 (i.e, final_output_i = [outout_i >= 0.5]).
- weights should be integral and in the range [-20, 20].

What I have tried so far:

- Noticed that output_1 is XOR(i1, i2), and output_2 is IMPLIES(i1, i2).
- Attempted back-propagation with 1000 epochs. Did not get 100% train accuracy.

I cannot find a better way than to simply make guesses about some weights and try to make others conform to them. What would be a better approach to this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by weights should be integral? Or by a 2-2-2 neural network, 2 input neurons, 2 hidden, 2 output? Then what is the 2nd output neurons doing (one output neurons seems to be 2 - i1 + i2, is that right?). Further, for binary input f(i1, i2) can equal 1, 2, or 3, but you said the output is binary (i.e. 0 or 1), how does that work?

Comment: Nice questions, Will. So, I will answer in order. Weights are integral means that the weights are integers. 2-2-2 network is as you noted, 2 inputs, 2 hidden and 2 outputs. The function that the network should compute is f(i1, i2) = (2 - i1 + i2)b. The suffix just means that the output is binary -- 1==01, 2==10, 3==11. So, for the input i1=1, and i2=1, we should get the output 2 -- o1=1, o2=0.

Comment: Aha thanks that makes much more sense now, thanks. Another few questions, am I allowed to use non-integer biases? Can I change the activation function to ReLU? And can I use three hidden neurons instead of two? If so I can write a network that nearly does what you want (hard to satisfy the integer weight requirement though...), but I think it's quite difficult to do with only two hidden neurons, which might be why your network is struggling to train. (The rough intuition being that implementing XOR requires two ReLU neurons, and IMPLIES another one, due to the number of linear regions)

Comment: Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question so it contains all relevant information and is clear and reads well to someone who encounters it for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion D.W. I will keep it in mind for my future posts. In this scenario, I think that question is concise and well stated. Everything I clarified for Will was a restatement. I only added an example to it. Please let me know if you disagree, and also let me know what I should add to the description. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding my comments into an answer that doesn't quite fit your criteria (and correcting what turned out to be shoddy intuition in the comments). I'm using ReLU neurons rather than sigmoid, I hope that is still useful!

I think the network in the image below does the required task. Hopefully it is clear what I mean, the two hidden neurons are each only active for one datapoint, either the 10 input or the 01 input. Then the first output is active unless the input is 10, i.e. unless the first hidden neuron is active, and the other output neuron is activated by either hidden neuron.

Does that help? I find sigmoids hard to think about, but I suspect you could design a network using sigmoids with similar ideas?

[image]